# Converting a .sql file to NoSQL (MongoDB) - MAC

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

I have .sql file, I want to convert it to NoSQL, as I have a coursework on MongoDB.

What application can I use or how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In a quick Google search, I found [this website](http://www.csvjson.com/sql2json) that converts CREATE and INSERT INTO statements to a JSON or Javascript format. However, if you want to create a different database structure (which I would probably recommend), you might want to program a Python script to create a JSON file to import to MongoDB. I guess it all depends on what you want to create.